# Ubuntu 22.10 has been released, and posts about it are no longer (generally) off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

As of Thu Oct 20 19:13:20 UTC, 2022, Ubuntu 22.10 [has been released](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-October/000285.html) and posts about it are no longer off-topic purely for being about 22.10 (of course, posts still should meet all the other criteria [as described in the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help)).

This does not mean that questions posted before the release that were closed for being about 22.10 should be re-opened. They *may* be re-opened on a case-by-case basis, but not generally. If you have a question you feel should be re-opened, propose it should be re-opened [on Meta Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask) (i.e., this site).

Also note that [as mentioned in the release-notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-notes/27976) (toward the bottom of that page), Ubuntu Unity is an official flavor.

Comment: I have added Ubuntu Unity here: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JanHus this isn't the place to rant about issues or bugs.  That's why you **file bugs against Ubuntu** to get things addressed.  Comments here should be regarding **this post** and not Ubuntu as a whole.